# New Theme.AppCompat ActionBar height

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

When using version 21 of appcompat library, `?android:attr/actionBarSize` returns 48 dips as if it was Holo theme and not Material. In fact it's a bit bigger - 56 dips.

Has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no workaround needed. If you're using `?android:attr/actionBarSize` android will look up the value in the plattform you're currently using. The result will be 48dp if you're running an Android-Version below 5.0, obviously.
Since you're using the `appcompat-v7` library in your project you should use `?actionBarSize`. This will return 56dp as expected, because the system will look up the value in your project, which has the actionBarSize defined because of the appcompat-library.

If you wanna try this on your own, here's a little code-snippet to test the described behaviour:

```
int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize, R.attr.actionBarSize };
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(new TypedValue().data, textSizeAttr);
float heightHolo = a.getDimension(0, -1);
float heightMaterial = a.getDimension(1, -1);

Log.d("DEBUG", "Height android.R.attr.: " + heightHolo + "");
Log.d("DEBUG", "Height R.attr.: " + heightMaterial + "");
```

**Note:** This will return the size in pixels. As an example on my Nexus 5, which is running 4.4 at the moment, it returns 144px(48dp) for *android.R.attr.actionBarSize* and 168px (56dp) for *R.attr.actionBarSize*.

Comment: testing this code on a project with appcompat v21, On Nexus 4 (v5.0.0), this code will return a value of 112px for booth... Nexus 5 (v5.0.1) booth returns 168px.

Comment: Makes sense since the Nexus 4 has a 720p resolution while the N5 has a 1080p one.

Comment: but also that booth values are the same? In your example you say to recieve two different results (144px & 168px)

Comment: Oh yeah I get what you mean. The `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` has been 48 dp on all versions below Lollipop. Now on 5.0 `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` and `R.attr.actionBarSize` are the same (56dp).

Comment: don't forget `a.recycle();`

Answer (score -1):

These worked for me using appcompact v-21

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:actionBarSize">46dp</item>
            <item name="actionBarSize">46dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This is not good in general. There are more actionBarSizes then just 46dp - landscape phone (smaller), tablets (bigger)...